# Remote debugging with Xdebug causes PHP script execution to halt

Tags: php, tcp, xdebug, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug remote PHP scripts using `xdebug`.  When `xdebug` is enabled for a website, if `xdebug` is able to make a `tcp` connection, the PHP script freezes as though waiting for a breakpoint to be executed.  The JavaScript portion of the webpage is displayed correctly, just waiting on the PHP code to return data required to complete the page.

This has worked in the past.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.

If `xdebug` is unable to make establish a TCP session with the remote host, all works as expected.

I am using Angular 10 as my development environment and PhpStorm as my IDE.

Environment:

```
Debian bullseye (testing)
Apache2.4
PHP 7.4.11
mpm_prefork
xdebug.so 2.9.8
```

I have also tried `xdebug.so v2.8.x and v3.0.0 (Beta)` to no effect.

Current `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini`:

```
#set xdebug flags/values
zend_extension=xdebug.so    

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=MyClientIP    
xdebug.remote_port=9099
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
    
#xdebug logger
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
```

While I am using PhpStorm to develop my application, this issue it is not related to my IDE.  To illustrate this I downloaded [`dbgbClient.exe`](https://xdebug.org/files/binaries/dbgpClient.exe) from xdebug.org.

When using the script a session is created between the client and server.

Client output:

```
dbgpClient.exe  -p 9099 -f
Xdebug Simple DBGp client (0.4.1)
Copyright 2019-2020 by Derick Rethans

Waiting for debug server to connect on port 9099.
Connect from 10.130.189.1:39144
DBGp/1.0: Xdebug 2.9.8 — For PHP 7.4.11
Debugging file:///home/init/DEV/MT4/php-services/ClassAPI.php (ID: 70831/PHPSTORM)
1 | feature_get
1 | supports_async: supported > 0
```

xdebug.log from server:

```
[70831] Log opened at 2020-10-14 20:59:24
[70831] I: Connecting to configured address/port: myClientIP:9099.
[70830] Log opened at 2020-10-14 20:59:24
[70830] I: Connecting to configured address/port: MyClientIP:9099.
[70831] I: Connected to client. :-)
[70831] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/init/DEV/MT4/php-services/ClassAPI.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.11" protocol_version="1.0" appid="70831" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.9.8"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[70830] I: Connected to client. :-)
[70830] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/init/DEV/MT4/php-services/ClassAPI.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.11" protocol_version="1.0" appid="70830" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.9.8"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

At this point the beginnings of the web page is created.

If I issue a `run` command and an extra carriage return or two, the debug session continues and the screen finishes.

Client example:

```
(cmd) run
2 | run > stopping/ok

(cmd)
Error while handling connection: Error reading length: EOF
Disconnect
Connect from 10.130.189.1:39146
DBGp/1.0: Xdebug 2.9.8 — For PHP 7.4.11
Debugging file:///home/init/DEV/MT4/php-services/ClassAPI.php (ID: 70830/PHPSTORM)
1 | feature_get
1 | supports_async: supported > 0

(cmd) run
2 | run > stopping/ok

(cmd)
Error while handling connection: Error reading length: EOF
Disconnect
```

xdebug log for the above:

```
[70831] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="1" feature_name="supports_async" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[70831] <- run -i 2
[70831] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[70831] <- run -i 3
[70831] Log closed at 2020-10-14 21:00:32

[70830] <- feature_get -i 1 -n supports_async
[70830] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="1" feature_name="supports_async" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

[70830] <- run -i 2
[70830] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="2" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[70830] <- run -i 3
[70830] Log closed at 2020-10-14 21:00:41

[70829] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[70829] Log closed at 2020-10-14 21:13:17

[70832] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[70832] Log closed at 2020-10-14 21:13:38
```

Thank you for reading this far.  I'm sure someone out there has a solution.

Comment: Just a note - I have tried using an SSH tunnel, mpm-event (count not get it working at all).  This behivor also occurs when trying to access the simple script <?php  phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: First of all, I would suggest to record small screencast showing this all in action (preferably using an IDE) -- it may reveal some missing bits/nuances. This can be some test code (so no real project names etc is shown if you do not want to).

Comment: Other than that: 1) I see 2 simultaneous debug sessions in the first Xdebug log fragment (and 4 in the 2nd log fragment). It could be your Angular making API calls ... That's why testing it on a simple PHP page with minimal code (e.g. `<?php $a = 1; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo "$c\n";` -- every statement on it's own line) should be easier to follow. PhpStorm can run few simultaneous sessions.

Comment: 2) If Xdebug connects to debug client/IDE .. and it hits breakpoint, then yes -- it will be staying there waiting for response. That's why `run` command helps -- it tells "continue exiting the script". I suggest to open up Breakpoints window in PhpStorm and remove them all. In PhpStorm, it's also possible that it stops because of "Break on first line..." or similar (another) option -- usually happens if no path mapping for that entry script is available... Check Xdebug section in PhpStorm settings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried with the same results.  `xdebug` is acting like it should stop at the first line of PHP code even though no such configuration exists.  I have tried local and remote debug sessions with out success.  Once a session is established, the script stops as if is waiting at a breakpoint.

Comment: 1) PhpStorm has 2 options that start with "Force break at first line..." text (`Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Xdebug` -- try disabling both of hem. 2) It would be good to see Xdebug log for such failing session with PhpStorm (the simple file of course, not real code). It may give some ideas.

Comment: 3) How to collect logs from IDE side: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collecting-logs (log is written in `idea.log` file -- `Help | Show Log in...`)

Comment: The Phpstorm logs do not have any mention of xdebug.  This issue happens if not using Phpstorm.  Using the simple cli client dgbcClient.exe to causes the same issue.  Examples of the xdebug log can be found above.  I build a new Debian server from 'stable'.  Simple, nothing but apache php7.3 xdebug and mpm_prefork.. Same issues.  It may come to loading a debugging version of xdebug..

Comment: OK, np here. No point to force anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out there is something between my development PC connected to my companies network via VPN.  I all worked at one time.  Thanks to IT tightening the security screws (`firewall rules`).

Although my PhpStorm would see the `PHPSTORM` cookie and establish a TCP session on the correct port, the protocol would not continue to completion.  I'm guessing there is some type if smart firewall on the network.

The secret was to establish a ssh tunnel between my PC and the linux server like so:

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 username_goes_here@hostname_goes_here
```

I also modified my `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini` as so: (The magic sauce is `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1`

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so    
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log    
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Thus the ssh tunnel will connect to port 9000 on the server with local port 9000 on the PC as the other end of the tunnel.

Then all that had to be done is to setup PhpStorm.  For that (and where these instructions originated) see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html).

Just a note - I only tested a php script access though a web browser. I have not tested a CLI based PHP script, but I'm guessing the answer is much the same.

If you need more information on ssh port forwarding (tunneling) see [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

Comment: FYI - To debug remote PHP CLI scripts add -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 in the 'Interpreter options" field

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part:

> Error while handling connection: Error reading length: **EOF**
> Disconnect

`xdebug` is not meant to connect to remote (live) sites, to begin with.

And even if `stunnel` is working, it might still fail to connect back for some reason ...eg.

```
xdebug.remote_host=EXTERNAL_ROUTER_IP
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

And the port-forward `:9099` to the internal `MyClientIP` in the router.

Comment: Remote debugging of php scripts has worked as late as last month. While your comment regarding the corporate firewall has value, part of my trouble shooting I was able to connect from the server to the client using telnet ClientIP 9099. In addition the command line client on my pc showed connection as well as the xdebug logs.  I believe the EOF indicated the client closing the connection.  There is something between Apache2, xdebug and php4.7.11 causing a race or lock issue.  BTW there is nothing in the php logs.

Comment: `xdebug` has it's own logs and this has little to do with apache. And I didn't mean any corporate firewall, but obviously the one on the web-server... `netstat` should also show what is going on. It cannot work with only one connection; eg. when it breaks at a break-point and then cannot resume the execution.

Comment: The reverse traffic might simply not be routed ...updated my answer.

Comment: I tried two Linux (Debian) servers on the same subnet.  One running Apache, PHP7.4, php-xdebug 2.9.6 with the simple script <php phpinfo() ?>.

Comment: Same issue.  It seems that xDebug is waiting at a break point that does not exists.

When the client issue a run command (twice) the page paint and an EOF is reported in the client.  The xdebug log shows 'Log closed'

I also tired downgrading to PHP 7.3 and associated apps.  Same issue.

Ugh